# Make the sound of an audience cheering a custom text

Tags: editing, audio, software-recommendation

I want to make the sound of a group of people (like an audience) cheering a user defined text.

Is it possible to achieve this easily?

I tried googling, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're asking. Could you re-phrase the question, giving us a little more detail about exactly what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, and the problem you're having.

Comment: You mean generating a audio-file of people cheering a text that you can change at any minute? Either look into neural-network voice-imitation or hire a few people to chant stuff. Personally, I would recommend the latter (artificial voices always sound creepy and off in my opinion).

Comment: @stib I have only tried to find some tool online. By _I want to make audience cheer a user defined text._ I mean to make an audio file that will have a cheer of audience for the text we provide. Florian, I agree, computer generated might not sound good.

Comment: OK, I edited the question to make it clearer. Before it sounded like you wanted to know how to make people cheer, like those signs that say "applause" in live studio recordings

Comment: @stib thanks. So it's like text to audio but the audio should be a group cheering that text not single person.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of people, you could get a few people to do the recording and use multiple takes of them saying the lines, then mix the takes together.